# Scraping Table - Getting different data from TR depending on odd or even

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to scrape a table but i have an issue where the data is different depending on it being an **odd row** or and **even row**

An example of the rows is displayed below:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      1<sup>st</sup>                        (9)                    
   </td>
   <td></td>
   <td class="ixt">
      <strong class="name">
      3                            <a href="/racing/profiles/horse/897171/fleeting-visit">
      Fleeting Visit                            </a>
      </strong>
   </td>
   <td class="ixt"><a href="/racing/profiles/trainer/43295/eve-johnson-houghton" class="name">Eve Johnson Houghton</a></td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>9-5                                            </td>
   <td class="ixt">
      <a href="/racing/profiles/jockey/77823/j-p-fahy" class="name">J P Fahy</a>
   </td>
   <td class="mobile-hdn">
      9/4f                                            
   </td>
</tr>

<tr class="note">
   <td colspan="8" data-mobile-colspan="7">
      <strong class="desktop-hdn">SP 9/4f</strong> Chased leaders, led over 2f out, stayed on well, eased towards finish opened 2/1                        
   </td>
</tr>
```

On the first TR i would like to get the horses name (Fleeting Visit) and on the second TR i would like to get the comments ( Chased leaders, led over 2f out, stayed on well, eased towards finish opened 2/1.

This follows for every horse so any odd rows will be the horses name and any even rows will be the comments. I have tried to run the script as below but it takes such a long time

```
foreach($getcommentdetails2 as $getcommentdetails22)
{   
    $count = 0;
    foreach($getcommentdetails22->childNodes as $node)  
        if(!($node instanceof \DomText))      
            $count++;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        if ($i % 2 == 0)
        {
            echo $horsecomment = strtolower(trim(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z ]+/", "", preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/","",trim($getcommentdetails22->childNodes->item($i)->childNodes->item(4)->nodeValue)))));
        }
        else
        {
            echo  $comment = $getcommentdetails22->childNodes->item($i)->nodeValue;
            // $results = $db->query("UPDATE Race_Records SET comments='$comment',Horse2 ='$horsecomment'   WHERE Horse='$horsecomment'");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`{ }` is required in loop `foreach($getcommentdetails22->childNodes as $node)`.

```
foreach($getcommentdetails2 as $getcommentdetails22)
{   
    $count = 0;
    foreach($getcommentdetails22->childNodes as $node)  
    {
        if(!($node instanceof \DomText))      
        $count++;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
        {
            if ($i % 2 == 0)
            {
                echo $horsecomment = strtolower(trim(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z ]+/", "", preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/","",trim($getcommentdetails22->childNodes->item($i)->childNodes->item(4)->nodeValue)))));
            }
            else
            {
                echo  $comment = $getcommentdetails22->childNodes->item($i)->nodeValue;
                // $results = $db->query("UPDATE Race_Records SET comments='$comment',Horse2 ='$horsecomment'   WHERE Horse='$horsecomment'");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it actually worked without it but this still takes forever to pull the data